# A question about Diode Clamps

Tags: diodes, dc-offset, diode-clamp

I was just wondering out of curiosity... In the following circuit, if I were to supply a steady DC voltage to Vin and another to the Offset input, would this be true:

*Vout = Vin - Offset*

[image: Schematics]

Answer (score 1):

No, it's more like the following:

$$V_{out} = 
\begin{cases} 
  V_{in},       & \text{if } V_{in} \lt  0.6V + Offset \\ 
  0.6V + Offset, & \text{if } V_{in} \geq 0.6V + Offset 
\end{cases} 
$$

Comment: Ok. Well is there a way to subtract a certain voltage from another. I want to know this because I am trying to remove a DC offset from an Op-Amp's output with a DC offset. The input of the op-amp would be a steady DC voltage so I don't think a Cap would work!

Comment: That should be another question, I think. Best to post what you have and what the issue is that needs to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove DC offset from the output, there are standard ways to go about it. A quick google search brings up [this appnote](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/tutorials/MT-037.pdf), which shows you how to trim offset on page 6. You basically inject a compensating voltage or current at the input. Or, use a single op-amp package that has pins for offset adjustment.

Comment: The thing is I am using a dual supply op-amp and applying a virtual ground with a voltage divider. All I want to do is remove that offset!

Comment: Hm, it's starting to sound like you're not looking to remove offset in the traditional sense (which means compensating for inherent op-amp errors). It almost sounds like you are trying to couple a signal biased around virtual ground to ground.

If that's the case, a coupling capacitor will do the trick. Posting a schematic would help clear things up.